# Mount permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

I want to do this:
Mount a network folder.
Read files from that folder.

I'm doing something like:

```
 mount //10.19.6.40/folder/ /mnt/folder/ -o username="user",password="pass",dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

My problem is, to do that I have to set folder access permissions, on the source server, to "Others" and I don't wan to do that. (Don't want users from that server to access that folder)

So, how can I mount a network folder without having to change permissions on the source server?

Comment: you've got the same userid on both server ?

Comment: No, I do not have the same userid

Comment: what is the network  server running? Windows or Unix/Linux?

Comment: Linux for both.

Comment: Is Samba on the server side using a username map? Is the `username="user"` you have in your mount command line the name of the user who owns the files on the server? If you use the client to create a new file on the server after mounting the filesystem, who is the file owned by?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you have to have permission to read the files on the source server before you can read them on the destination server. If you don't have an account on the source server with the same UID as on the destination, it will be very difficult at best to read these files. If you have root permissions on the destination and the mount is exported with the `no_root_squash` option (rare), you can read the files using root on the destination server. In most other cases, you'll have to change permissions on the files, likely from the source server.

Comment: I think the question is about CIFS, not NFS. I've never seens an NFS mount with `-o username=` etc. and so UIDs aren't relevant either; all files' UIDs become whatever `uid=` value is passed as mount option.